# my android app get ads restriction from admob with the reason site behavior: navigation but i can't understand why?

Tags: java, android, layout, admob, ads

my android app get ads restriction from admob with the reason site behavior: navigation but i can't understand why?

this is my app and i review it on many devices mobiles tablets and on many screen sizes from small to xx-large screen and everything is okay.

but admob still insist on the same problem which is Site Behavior: Navigation without giving me any more details?

this is my app store link
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.wallpaperfountain.bluerosewallpapers62

can any one help me and told me why and where is the error in my app?

i solved all the layout problems in my app and now everything work clearly and i can't find any problem but although admob team insist that my app have a problem without telling me where exactly so i hope from expert people to install my app and tell me if they can figure where is the problem

Answer (score -1, accepted):

hello so after a while i figure the problem.

my app was going well until i upgrade the target version to android 13 or api 33, my app is using external storage permission but in api 33 to ask for this permission you need a new permission that introduced just for api 33 and up, so my app target api 33 but devices with api 33 and up can't use it because i was asking for the wrong permission and that why admob restrict ads on my app, after i fix everything admob serve ads to my app again

for more details read here
[Android API 33 permissions are not granted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73826323/android-api-33-permissions-are-not-granted)